# Какие есть плагины для стилизации placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, плагин

Подскажите пожалуйста какой-нибудь хороший плагин для стилизации `placeholder`. Чтобы я мог выбрать `input's` в которых нужно заменить `placeholder` на кастомизированный желательно с возможностью задания своего класса в настройках.

Перерыл уже кучу плагинов, все не то

Comment: Чем вам не подходит кастомизация через псевдо-елемент `::placeholder`?

Comment: @E_K, тем, что не поддерживается IE9

Comment: Зачем поддерживать IE9 если даже IE11 три года как уже деприкейтед.

Comment: @AlexanderZaytsev ты прав как никогда

Comment: @AlexanderZaytsev, в тз указана поддержка IE9

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi есть такое https://mathiasbynens.github.io/jquery-placeholder/ что нашел

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366021/placeholder-in-ie9